# How to get java main class from jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have an executable jar and i want to know the name of java `main class` from this jar

My question are if there is a `java cmd` to get this from jar metadata ?

Comment: What if there's more than one?

Comment: Uh... you mean like opening it in WinRAR and looking at the manifest?
Example:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: core.BlackStar

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes

Comment: @CConard96 but not when using Artificate : 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: 
Implementation-Version...
Project-Artifact....
Build-Version: ...
Build-Time: ....
Build-Scm-Version:....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use unix command :
`unzip -p XXX.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

or you can use jar commad
`jar tf XXX.jar` and see the content of `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: For a long time, I was poking around in the dark - looking at java -cp class.etc . This finally worked!

Comment: `jar xf XXX.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is the complete answer for using the jar command

Answer (score 8):

Technically a jar file can contain more than one main class.

When java executes a jar file, it looks in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside the jar to find the entrypoint.

There is no direct command to get this information, but you can unpack the jar (it's just a zip file) and look into the manifest yourself.

More about the manifest: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html

More about application entrypoints: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html